# Need to know the extra boxes connected to exterior outlet

Tags: electrical, outdoor

So I have an exterior outlet that seems to be up to code. But I want to move the outlet 4’ so that I can put pavers in this area. 
Before I do I need to know if these two boxes can be moved. 
The outlet was originally setup for a jacuzzi so the extra boxes may have been for that. The new outlet will just be for a fan or Bluetooth speaker aka low usage.
Here are some pictures. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I added a pic of the middle box - It doesn’t really serve a purpose

[image: pic of top box][image]

Comment: Do you want to move 4' away from where the power probably starts, or 4' closer to where the power starts? And where is wire going from the junction box? (Since it has multiple conduits, I assume there's multiple paths. It wouldn't hurt to open the junction box and snap a pic, as well.

Comment: It looks like the conduit coming out of the ground may be rigid metal (this allows for a shallow burial but won’t be easy to move). is the breaker feeding the receptacle GFCI ? That should be (not just the in use cover that is not up to code because of the opening on top this would have never passed an inspection. Can you move it sure but you may find this a larger job than a simple move.

Comment: I want to move the new outlet (gfi) 4’ further from the house

Comment: In that case, to eliminate the junction box, you'll need to pull new (longer) wire. Which you might want to do anyway, as that cable looks suspiciously like cordage rather than wet-rated conduit wire - it is highly unusual to run cable in conduit, rather than individual THWN wires.

Answer (score 2):

### There are few "simple" moves with buried conduit.

Can it be moved? - Almost certainly.

How much work will that be? - Nobody can tell you until you figure out what goes where, and that will almost certainly involve excavating the 3 buried conduits if you have no plan indicating where they run to/from - unless you get lucky and find that when you open the box, two of them are empty. Don't bet on that being the case.

Note: **moved** may really mean "partially reconstructed anew in a different location to effect "moving" the outlet and junction box (if the junction box is still needed in the new configuration") rather than reusing much or any of what you have there.

The non-outlet "boxes" shown are *apparently* a junction box (the big thing up higher) and a Tee down lower which is not really a box, at least with small conduit. You may not need them in the new configuration, it depends what they are doing or were doing for the Hot tub functions you are not replicating after the move.

Comment: Hi I just added two pictures of the “boxes” and I honestly think the previous homeowner just used what was available. I see no technical reason for the two boxes to be there